# How to find top 3 frequency elements from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

```
d=[[(u'BAKING', 51)], [(u'ACCESS', 4)],[(u'CUTE', 2)], [(u'RED', 3)],[(u'FINE', 59)], [(u'ACCESS', 49)],[(u'YOU', 97)], [(u'THANK', 41)]]
```

I have a list of tuples with words and their corresponding frequency. Now how to find top 3 frequency words from these?

```
t=[]
for items in d:
k=items[0]
print len(k)
for j in k:
    t.append(j)
print t
m=[t[i:i+2] for i  in range(0, len(t), 2)]
print m
j=Counter(m)
```

This is giving me error, m is list it should be dictionary :( How to convert it into dictionary

Comment: I tried to use counter() but it didnt work

Comment: Also if there are duplicates like here [(u'ACCESS', 4)], [(u'ACCESS', 49)] then it should add up it's frequencies [(u'ACCESS', 53)] , I am confused how to do so !

Comment: May we see your attempt involving `counter()`? That will show readers that you have tried something `:-)`.

Comment: t=[]
for items in d:
    k=items[0]
    print len(k)
    for j in k:
        t.append(j)
print t
m=[t[i:i+2] for i  in range(0, len(t), 2)]
print m

Comment: @KanikaSingh: I added a solution below that also takes duplicates into account. Please let me know whether that solves your problem and whether you need further explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itemgetter` and `itertools.chain` to get this task done:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain

sorted(list(chain.from_iterable(d)),  key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[0:3]
```

This will give you:

```
[(u'YOU', 97), (u'FINE', 59), (u'BAKING', 51)]
```

Some explanation: The `chain` command flattens your list of lists, so that you end up with a list of tuples (these might be easier to handle than the list of tuples). This list is then sorted according to the second element of the tuple using `itemgetter` and you then select the first three elements.

EDIT:

Just read your comment about multiple entries. One way to do it is the following:

```
import collections
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain

result_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
newL = list(chain.from_iterable(d))
for tu in newL:
     result_dict[tu[0]].append(tu[1])
```

This will give you

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'CUTE': [2], u'BAKING': [51], u'THANK': [41], u'ACCESS': [4, 49], u'YOU': [97], u'FINE': [59], u'RED': [3]})
```

Now you can sum get the sum of the entries in the list like this:

```
res = {k: sum(v) for k,v in result_dict.iteritems()}
```

and the best three items like that:

```
sorted(res.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[0:3]
```

In this case it is:

```
[(u'YOU', 97), (u'FINE', 59), (u'ACCESS', 53)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer:

```
sorted(d, key = lambda x: x[0][1], reverse = True)
```

Comment: sorted(d, key=lambda x: x[0][1], reverse=True) will work because d is a list of list of objects

Comment: That works, too. But this way you don't get the duplicates (see comments below the question).